can't copy specific characters from a pdf. what is the reason and how do i diagnose?
The PDF is not protected
It needs no password.I read it from Adobe reader flatpak in Ubuntu and the properties tab indicates no security and printing, copying and extraction are allowed. I tried online DRM remover and the issue persists so no DRM.

When I select text (both in Evince and Okular) some characters are not selected and these characters are the ones not copied and I find gibberish. in browser and Adobe reader the selection highlights everything but when I copy I get the same result
I tried to extract images thinking that these characters are rendered as images but found none
I listed the fonts and found two TrueType(CID) fonts with identity-H encoding. But i cant extract the fonts using Fontbox or online tools

This can't be an encoding issue as some characters can be selected and copied. I suspect corrupted font but how to know for sure?
Here is the minimum reproducible sample page.pdf

It could be a specific Tamil/Malay font needs to be installed. It also might be that the PDF is damaged, or there might be steganography (hidden text) inside. BTW, some characters cannot be selected in Firefox browser, yet in Sumatra PDF or PDF-XChange Editor (both of which work well in Ubuntu in wine), they can be selected. I find they're faster to use, even under wine, than Okular.

There is not much can be done without relatively expensive font re-mappers. The task is very slow and laborious. So only suited to some simpler cases.
A PDF fixer Character remapping tool.

Every case is different, so we can only consider this example. The pedigree shows a site that occasionally distorts PDF content when especially used for re-optimising PDF contents. The problem is that example PDF has no conventional font with Unicode mapping. Ideally we would like to see something like this with a /ToUnicode numeric.
<</BaseFont/EAAAAA+NirmalaUI/DescendantFonts[9 0 R]/Encoding/Identity-H/Subtype/Type0/ToUnicode 10 0 R/Type/Font>>

However even in that case faults will often be found, if there are flaws in the CMAP. see the first image for some characters from many which have bad mapping.

The only solution is to go to the source used to produce the PDF and make necessary adjustments there. It is simply too difficult in most cases to try to reverse deletion of character mapping.

i opened the pdf in a debugger (iTextRUPS), and found the specified tounicode stream. I managed to delete the glyph ids and retain only the unicode id. then i used a python script to print them [அ,  ஆ,  இ,  ஈ,  உ,  ஊ,  எ,  ஏ,  ஐ,  ஒ,  ஓ,  க,  ச,  ஜ,  ஞ,  ட,  ண,  த,  ந,  ன,  ப,  ம,  ய,  ர,  ற,  ல,  ள,  ழ,  வ,  ஷ,  ஸ,  ா,  ி,  ,  ு,  ெ,  ே,  ை ] only these glyphs are found and rest are missing. i cross checked the missing letters in copied text and they ceem to correspond i.e: only the glyphs in the above list are selectable and copyable.
It seems part of the cmap is deleted

to deal with these pdfs with corrupted fonts and missing cmaps, I am willing to put in some time, effort and code (java preferably) to repair the fonts if it comes to it as the only available tools are paid. where is good starting point? (i guess it is extracting the glyphs but how?) (perhaps it deserves its own question :p )

I thought of extracting the glyphs and using ocr to create a new cmap and then parsing the document (i have performance constraints so i can't afford to ocr the entire document)
